# Como puedo parsear una fecha en Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-ee

HOla estoy queriendo parsear una fecha para poder comparar. Este es el codigo que estoy aplicando:

```
LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.now();
        String sDate1 = jsonPath.get("data.expiresAt");
        DateFormat formatter;
        formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        Date date_temp=null;

        try{
            date_temp= (Date) formatter.parse(sDate1);
        }catch (ParseException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Pero cuando aplico esto y corro el scrip me da esto:
Unparseable date: "2022-11-18T12:45:56.258Z

Answer (score 2):

Estás mezclando la clase `java.util.Date` y `SimpleDateFormat` con las clases del paquete `java.time`. Permíteme un consejo: Intenta **no usar en ningún caso** `java.util.Date`, `Calendar` o `SimpleDateFormat` es una API antigua llena de malas ideas/implementaciones que hace más de 8 años que se desaconseja usar (desde la aparición de Java 8 en 2014 e incluso antes, con el uso de joda-time).

Por otro lado, el texto `"2022-11-18T12:45:56.258Z"` es el formato [ISO estándar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), por lo que no necesitas especificarlo porque suele ser el patrón por defecto de la mayoría de las librerías/clases que trabajan con fechas en prácticamente todos los lenguajes de programación.

Puedes hacer algo como

```
Instant expiration = Instant.parse(sDate1);
boolean expired = Instant.now().isBefore(expiration);
```

Comment: Justo eso iba a decir a OP, desde Java 8+ la [API `time`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) vino a corregir y facilitar muchas cosas con respecto a las fechas, los tiempos, los períodos, los intervalos. Antes todas estas cosas eran muy complicas en Java y ahora puedes resolverlo con un par de líneas de código, como se muestra en tu respuesta. Aparte de eso, no funcionaba porque el formato no concordaba con la cadena que se le estaba pasando.

Comment: Correcto, `Instant.parse` usa ya por defecto el formato ISO estándar, que es justo lo que se le está pasando